# Can Nagios send alerts for periodic events?

Tags: nagios

Is there any plugin or facility in nagios which can do this:
For example, the CPU load rises to 80% for 2seconds would not be a problem. I want to get an alert if it remains at 80%++ for at least 5mins. is it possible??

Comment: Seems like this question belongs to serverfault instead of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Just set your `retry_interval` to `1`, and your `max_check_attempts` to `5`, and Nagios will retry the check 5 times (5mn) before sending out an alert. If the problem persists after all of the retries, it will send the alert.